# How to change the default Terminal of VS Code to use Bash?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code on Windows and the default terminal is currently PowerShell. But I like Bash, but I couldn't change the terminal to use Bash.

I tried to change it from the settings and as always I looked it up on Youtube and also searched in Chrome but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution.

So, any thoughts?

Comment: Install Git/Git Bash in your C: drive.  I've personally found that if it exists anywhere else, VSC can't detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to VSC and type **Ctrl + P** and search **>Terminal: Select default profile** then choose your bash profile. (Ensure you installed Bash in Operation System Disk)